# In the Django project,how to rebuild the model classes by migrations file?

Tags: django, database, migration, rebuild

In the Django project, if the model folder files are deleted, is it possible to use the migrations folder files to rebuild the model classes?

Comment: You can try running `makemigrations` (if you don't have the tables in a database already) and then [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models). Don't know how to get the models from migration files directly though.

Answer (score 1):

@mohammadKazemSamiel- I tried the following with my Postgres Database.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

This will look at the Database configured in settings.py and based on the SQLschema will spit out the model in models.py. Though you might need to edit few fields once the models are generated.

Comment: This command works properly when there is a database. However, there is no database and no model classes.
The only thing that exists are migration outputs.